# EF ignores Included properties on Select

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have data structure like this

```
public class Author
{
    ...
}

public class Comment
{
    public long Userid { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Blog
{
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to retrieve some data from DB i use following construction

```
IRepository<Blog> blogsRepository = _repositoryFactory.Create<Blog>();
IQueryable<Blog> blogsQuery = blogsRepository.Query().Include(x => x.Author);
List<BlogsData> blogsData = blogsQuery.Select(x => new BlogsData
                                                        {
                                                            Blog = x,
                                                            Commented = x.Comments.Any(z => z.Userid == userId)
                                                        }).ToList();
```

where `BlogsData` is

```
public class BlogsData
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public bool Commented { get; set; }
}
```

But after all data was fetched to `List<BlogsData>` the `Blog.Author` property is `null`.

I don't understand, why `Include(x => x.Author)` is ignored in this case?
And how to get around this problem?

Comment: Sometimes when EF is projecting elements, if `.Include()` is not the last statement, some other statements will prevent the include from working (that has been my experience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day, my experience in EF is you need also to add it in select

add Author in

```
public class BlogsData
{
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public bool Commented { get; set; }
}
```

and add it in

```
List<BlogsData> blogsData = blogsQuery.Select(x => new BlogsData
                                                    {
                                                        Author x.Author,
                                                        Blog = x,
                                                        Commented = x.Comments.Any(z => z.Userid == userId)
                                                    }).ToList();
```